# I want to add image when I share my website link

Tags: wordpress, image, meta

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBZL8.png)I have added image in my website. I want to show that image when I share my website link.It is showing only in whatsapp not in facebook and skype.

My website link is: https://www.telotrovo.it/

I have tried this code:

```html
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.telotrovo.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/siteimage.jpg"/>

<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.telotrovo.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/siteimage.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Where would you like to share, is it facebook ?

Comment: Yes, I want to show image when I share my link in any platform. Right now it showing in whats app only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook,Skype and others are using Open Graph Protocol to get those. I have these in one of my sites:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Site Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my.website.com" />
<meta property="og:image:url" content="http://my.website.com/images/thumb.png" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Site description" />
```

And the image displayed as the link preview on Skype and Facebook is the thumb image specified in og:image:url.

These four should be present in your  tag. Also make sure you add the XML NameSpace to the  tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Working in whatsapp

Comment: You can change the image size then try this code is working for me

Comment: Please change image dimesions

Comment: But this showing default image. My image is different

Comment: What image you want to show please add that image path in meta

Comment: My be  issue is with the facebook cache and solution is to refresh the facebook cache by going to the link. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

and pressing the button "Fetch New Scrape information".

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can try following ,

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.telotrovo.it/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/siteimage.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200">
```

Image width should specify, minimum 200 X 200 , you can change it though

Comment: Working in whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.